# What's the solution to use a Material3 bottom sheet without changing the default theme in Kotlin Android app?

Tags: kotlin, android-layout

I don't want to apply AndroidManifest theme. What should I do?

Hello, I'm making an app.

My app default theme is Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
like this

```
    <style name="Theme.defaulttheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>
```

```
androidmafest.xml

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.defaulttheme"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
```

then I have to use the bottomsheet of material3.

but bottom sheet is MaterialComponents

I applied the theme to the bottom sheet, but only the color of the letter and button changed, and the bottom sheet of material 3 did not come out.

I think I've done everything I can. Like creating a custom theme or style on a bottom sheet and applying it

However, the bottom sheet continued to be the bottom sheet of Material Components.

The only solution I've found is the default theme Change to Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar. But I can't apply it like this because of the team problem.

what should i do?

Comment: can you let me know how you are creating you bottom sheet?